# Updating sql table with results from left join (sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a SQL server query. I'm trying to update an existing table (#Masterfile), based on the results of left joining the table with another outside source (table 2). Row 6 is basically a flag that says whether the ID exists in table b or not. I am new to sql (just started learning a couple of weeks ago) so my syntax is probably very basic. I left joined the #Masterfile with the new table of interest (Table 2) and then select the result (and update the column6_flag).

However, I get error, identifying the statement (, a.column6_flag = case when x.column9 is not NULL  then 1 else 0 end) as the culprit. Any help would be much appreciated!!! I tried looking at case when syntax again but can't identify why it's yielding error. When I comment out the case when portion of the query, it works.

Thanks again!

```
--Insert into #MasterFile 
 select distinct
     a.column1
     , a.column2
     , a.column3
     , a.column4
     , a.column5
     , a.column6_flag = case when x.column9 is not NULL  then 1 else 0 end
     , a.column7
     , x.column9
from 
    #Alldata a
left join 
    (select m.column9
     from #Masterfile m
     left join table2 n on m.id = n.id) x on a.id = x.id
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to move the case around so it's like this:

```
select distinct
a.column1
, a.column2
, a.column3
, a.column4
, a.column5
, case when x.column9 is not NULL  then 1 else 0 end AS column6_flag
, a.column7
, x.column9
from #Alldata a
left join 
(
select 
m.column9
from #Masterfile m
left join table2 n
on m.id=n.id
) x
on a.id=x.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `a.column6_flag` with just `column6_flag`

```
column6_flag = case when x.column9 is not NULL  then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1,
                column2,
                column3,
                column4,
                column5,
                column6_flag = CASE
                                 WHEN x.column9 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                               END,
                column7,
                x.column9
FROM   #Alldata a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.id,
                         m.column9
                  FROM   #Masterfile m
                         LEFT JOIN table2 n
                                ON m.id = n.id) x
              ON a.id = x.id
```